# Is Fortran in fixed-form source easier for a compiler to optimize?

Tags: optimization, fortran

From what I've found on the Internet, fixed format Fortran is something people still have to deal with occasionally in scientific computing. I've heard about it mostly in the context of maintaining old programs that would be very costly to rewrite in an easier-to-maintain form.

When writing a Fortran program from scratch though, is there any advantage to using the more restrictive fixed form over free form?

To be more specific, by an "advantage" I mean a case in which a program in fixed form will be more computationally efficient than an equivalent program in free form.

Comment: I think the question is more like "If I write the exact same code and put it in fixed form, will it be faster than if it was free form". This question has a well-defined answer.

Comment: @francescalus by an optimization advantage I meant a more efficient compiled program, not an easier-to-optimize source file for the compiler. In asking the question I hoped to avoid it coming across as opinion-based by asking about a speed advantage specifically, not "is fixed form better than free form." I may have neglected to make that clear.

Comment: Fixed vs free form is the easy part of this question : no difference. What is easier for a compiler to optimise is a much more difficult part to explain or understand. Free form might imply using more modern coding approaches, which can be helpful, but how to achieve optimal; that is elusive and can depend on the particular compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has some subtle aspects but the simple answer is "no" (for a compiler which understands both forms).

Compilers generally operate in a number of phases.  When it comes to optimization the compiler doesn't look at a line of source and determine what to do with it.

An early phase of compilation is the *lexical* phase.  This takes the source code and determines what tokens exist.  Consider the sources

```
do 77 i=1, 5
  x(i) = 1.0
77 continue
```

which is in free-form, and

```
      do77i=1,5
      x(i)=1.0
   77 continue
```

which is in fixed-form, and

```
      do 77 i=1,5
        x(i) = 1.0
   77 continue
```

which is valid in both.

After the lexical phase, the internal representation the compiler has is the same (at least exactly the same set of tokens are determined).  What happens next is independent of the pre-lexed source.

A complication is people often consider free-form to mean

```
x(1:5) = 1.0
```

because it's a Fortran 90+ way of writing the same assignment.

This could equally be written in fixed-form

```
      x(1:5) = 1.0
```

and the tokens are again the same.  Now, there could be differences in how a compiler treats the two approaches, but source form is not the key.

Comment: Indeed, much of the work of a compiler is unrelated to what _language_ the source code was written in, never mind the style of how it was written.